# Scheduling a Receive activity inside a NativeActivity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

In my workflow service I've got an interface with a large number of methods. All of these have been into usable activities using "Import Service Contract..." option.

The generated activities are fine, but I would like to make using them even simpler. Right now I need to remember about setting up the correlation handler and if I forget just one, it's sometimes difficult to find which `Receive` activity is at fault.

So I wanted to create a `NativeActivity` wrapper around my `Receive` activities which would have an `InArgument<CorrelationHandle>` with the `[RequiredAttribute]` flag set, to make things easy and clear.

Here's where I'm at:

```
public sealed class TestActivity : NativeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<CorrelationHandle> Handle { get; set; }
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<XName> ServiceContractName { get; set; }

    private Receive OnCGTaskCreate { get; set; }
    private Variable<CorrelationHandle> HandleVariable { get; set; }

    public TestActivity()
    {
        OnCGTaskCreate = new Receive()
        {
            OperationName = "OnCGTaskCreate",
            ServiceContractName = System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("{Service.Workflow}IWorkflowService"),
            Action = "Service.Workflow/IWorkflowService/OnCGTaskCreate",
            DisplayName = "OnCGAccountCreate_Receive",
            CanCreateInstance = false,
            Content = new ReceiveParametersContent
            {
                Parameters =
                {
                    { "Context", new OutArgument<WorkflowExecutionContext>() },
                    { "Entity", new OutArgument<CGTask>() }
                }
            },
        };
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddImplementationChild(OnCGTaskCreate);
        HandleVariable = new Variable<CorrelationHandle>("correlationHandle");
        OnCGTaskCreate.CorrelatesWith = new InArgument<CorrelationHandle>(HandleVariable);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(HandleVariable);
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var handle = Handle.Get(context);
        HandleVariable.Set(context, handle);
        OnCGTaskCreate.CorrelatesOn = new System.ServiceModel.MessageQuerySet() { { "key1", new XPathMessageQuery("sm:body()/xgSc:OnCGTaskCreate/xgSc:Context/xg0:WorkflowId") } };
        OnCGTaskCreate.ServiceContractName = ServiceContractName.Get(context);

        context.ScheduleActivity(OnCGTaskCreate, new CompletionCallback(OnCallCompleted));
    }

    private void OnCallCompleted(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance instance)
    {
      //figure this part out later
    }
}
```

The problem is I keep getting the following exception:

`The operation cannot be performed on variables of Handle subtypes.`

```
   at System.Activities.Variable`1.VariableLocation.set_Value(T value)
   at System.Activities.ActivityContext.SetValueCore[T](LocationReference locationReference, T value)
   at Service.Workflow.Activity.TestActivity.Execute(NativeActivityContext context) in Service.Workflow\Activity\TestActivity.cs:line 53
   at System.Activities.NativeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Additionally, since I've only ever used the `Receive` activities in the designer, I'm not sure if I'm implementing it properly in code.

Here's a sample XAML code for the Receive activity and how it's used in the designer:

```
                        <p:Receive Action="Service.Workflow/IWorkflowService/OnCGTaskCreate" DisplayName="OnCGTaskCreate_Receive" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Receive_1" OperationName="OnCGTaskCreate" ProtectionLevel="None" ServiceContractName="p1:IWorkflowService">
                          <p:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
                            <p:XPathMessageQuery x:Key="key1">
                              <p:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>
                                <ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
                                  <x:String x:Key="xg0">http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Base</x:String>
                                  <x:String x:Key="xgSc">Service.Workflow</x:String>
                                </ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
                              </p:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>sm:body()/xgSc:OnCGTaskCreate/xgSc:Context/xg0:WorkflowId</p:XPathMessageQuery>
                          </p:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
                          <p:Receive.CorrelatesWith>
                            <InArgument x:TypeArguments="p:CorrelationHandle">
                              <mca:CSharpValue x:TypeArguments="p:CorrelationHandle">handle</mca:CSharpValue>
                            </InArgument>
                          </p:Receive.CorrelatesWith>
                          <p:ReceiveParametersContent>
                            <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="acgsb:WorkflowExecutionContext" x:Key="Context" />
                            <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="acgsbc:CGTask" x:Key="Entity">
                              <mca:CSharpReference x:TypeArguments="acgsbc:CGTask">task</mca:CSharpReference>
                            </OutArgument>
                          </p:ReceiveParametersContent>
                        </p:Receive>
```

So, to summarize - how would I go about running the above XAML code by programmatically scheduling it inside a `NativeActivity`, in order to streamline it's usage?

EDIT:

The reason I'm using a `Variable` at all is because of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/02/26/misadventures-in-cachemetadata-wrapping-an-inner-activity-in-code.aspx) blog post describing how to schedule inner activities.

Sadly, this article is about scheduling something other than a `Receive` activity, so chances are it doesn't apply to my problem.

Comment: Not necessarily your problem but, for starters, do initializations (internal activities, variables and arguments) on constructor, not on `CacheMetadata`. `CacheMetadata` is called several times by the designer and workflow runtime and is not meant to be used like that.

Comment: @Jota Very true. The above code is the result of several (wild) attempts at solving the other issues, and I forgot to (re)move it.

Comment: Because of that, the variable that you're adding through `AddImplementationVariable()` isn't the same you're setting the value. The activity can only deal with variables that owns and your activity doesn't know `HandleVariable` when it reaches execute method.

Comment: Moreover, and I might be missing something, why do you need `HandleVariable`? Why not initialize `OnCGTaskCreate.CorrelatesWith` with `Handle`

Comment: @Jota Please note the EDIT I've made to the question. Note that I've tried both initiating the `Variable` in the `CacheMetadata` as well as in the constructor - the result was the same. I've also tried setting `OnCGTaskCreate.CorrelatesWith` with `Handle` (as per your suggestion), and while I didn't get any exceptions, the end result was that the workflow didn't react to the event so I kept trying other stuff. Of course it DOES work if I just use the `Receive` activity created from the "Import Service Contract" option, but this isn't what I'm trying to accomplish.